# Is there a way to get a line number (and column number) of the input file where java.util.Scanner failed?

Tags: java, input

When there is an error in an input file is it possible to find out in which line of the input file the scanner failed?

The following code always prints out the total lines in reader instead of line number where the error happened:

```
import java.io.LineNumberReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ScannerTests {

    static private final String text = "FUNCTION_BLOCK Unnamed_project\n\tVAR_INPUT\n\t\tUnnamed_variable1::REAL;\n\tEND_VAR\nEND_FUNCTION_BLOCK";

    @Test
    public void scannerLineNumberFailedTest() {

        LineNumberReader reader = new LineNumberReader(new StringReader(text));

        int lineNumber = -1;

        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(reader);
            sc.useDelimiter("\\s*\\b\\s*");

            sc.next("(?i)FUNCTION_BLOCK");
            String blockName = sc.next();
            assert sc.hasNext("(?i)VAR_INPUT");
            sc.next("(?i)VAR_INPUT"); 
            String variableName = sc.next();
            sc.next(":");                       // line of failure - got a unexpected '::'
            String type = sc.next("\\w+"); 
            sc.next(";");
            sc.next("(?i)END_VAR");             
            sc.next("(?i)END_FUNCTION_BLOCK");

            assert "Unnamed_project".equals(blockName);
            assert "Unnamed_variable1".equals(variableName);
            assert "REAL".equals(type);

            sc.close();
        } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {

            lineNumber = reader.getLineNumber() + 1;
            System.err.println("Error in line: " + lineNumber);
        }

        assert lineNumber == 3; 
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use a Scanner to parse the text of a programming language (or DSL). This is not a good idea, you should use a parser generator like ANTLR instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Scanner` does not track line numbers or character numbers.

You could try to implement this using a custom `FilterReader` that counts lines and characters, but I think that won't be accurate in all cases.  It will tell you how far you how far the scanner got through the stream, but it cannot take account of the fact that the scanner can read ahead a number of characters in a `hasNext` method and then wind back and read the input using a *different* `next` method.  For example:

```
if (sc.hasNext("[A-Z ]+")) {
   sc.nextInteger();
```

If the `nextInteger()` method call fails, the "current position" as reported by the `FilterReader` could be *many characters* past the stream position where the bad integer is detected.

In the worst case, this winding back can take you back past line boundaries ... depending on how you have configured the delimiters.  So (in theory) even the line numbers cannot be tracked with certainty.

---

The only way to track line and character numbers 100% accurately in all cases is to implement your own input parsing system that tracks these things itself ... through all of the forward and backward movement of its input stream cursor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not answer the question.

Comment: @Tuto - actually, it does.  It is just that it is not the answer you want to hear.

Comment: The expanded answer is an answer I can live with. Probably not enough to write a wrapper around Scanner, better to hit a a parser generator for this.

Comment: @Tuto you can use ANTLR to generate a lexer and/or a parser for your language

Comment: @Don - why do you suggest ANTLR and not one of the alternatives?  Why do you think he is unaware of ANTLR?